# How can I structure my azure durable functiona folder structure (language-typescript)?

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I want to use separate activity folders and orchestrator folders and include them inside them.
[image: current folder structure]
[image: needed folder structure]

The issue I'm facing is with the typescript callActivity(inside orchestrator), I cant call activities since we can't pass folder.
[image]

Comment: You can include the Activity functions and Orchestration functions in their respective separate folders, but you can't pass multiple parameters directly to an activity function. https://i.imgur.com/0UNVzlI.png - callActivity method requires 2 parameters as shown in your activity function code image.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the Activity functions and Orchestration functions in their respective separate folders, but you can't pass multiple parameters directly to an activity function.

[image]

`callActivity` method requires 2 parameters as shown in your activity function code image.

If you are passing the multiple activity functions with their inputs (values) to the **`callActivity`** method, then use arrays form of objects, tuples.

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#activity-functions) for more information.